# What are tickets?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I'm stuck on level 20 in Candy Crush, so I want to ask my friends for these "three tickets".

What does it require my friends to do? Do they have to be at a higher level than me? Do they have to complete a level? Will I be bothering them? What will facebook say to them?

Comment: Hi Anonymous181! I took out your second question about the bonus levels, as it should be its own separate question. Feel free to ask a new question if you are still curious about them!

Answer (score 1):

These tickets are not more than a single request, which your friends accept or decline. If three of your friends accept you can go on, they do not have any requiremens, just to accept. And Facebook is alright with that ^^